# Getting build exception for google-services.json file

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

When I'm running my flutter app using "run without debugging" I'm getting the following error -

Execution failed for task ':firebase_auth:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
>      Searched Location:

- C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.15.4\android\src\nullnull\google-services.json
- C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.15.4\android\src\debug\google-services.json
- C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.15.4\android\src\nullnullDebug\google-services.json
- C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.15.4\android\src\nullnull\debug\google-services.json
- C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.15.4\android\src\debug\nullnull\google-services.json
- C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.15.4\android\google-services.json

Why it is searching for google-services.json in flutter's pub-cache directory? I have it in right place "project/android/app/google-services.json" in that app level directory. Why gradle isn't searching it there? what do I do in this case?

THANKS FOR YOUR HELP!

Comment: Should I try by adding google-services.json file in any of the above directory mentioned in error?

Comment: Suthar, please write here problem decision, if it is.

Comment: What does that command does `run without debugging`?